# Increasing width of button in MessageBox in extjs4

Tags: extjs

How do I increase width of button in MessageBox in extjs4; I have long caption/text to put in button.

There is global property minButtonWidth but that is set for all buttons in application but I need long button on a specific message.

Comment: Can you post the code how you are creating messagebox with buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try showing the message box like this with the minButtonWidth config:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Address',
    msg: 'Please enter your address:',
    width: 300,
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
    multiline: true,
    fn: saveAddress,
    animateTarget: 'addAddressBtn',
    icon: Ext.window.MessageBox.INFO,
    ...
    minButtonWidth: 100
});
```